# Use command line npm modules as normal modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I and my friends were wondering how to require and use a `node module` which was designed to be used in the `CLI`

For ex: The `standard` [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/standard) is intended to be called via the command line by executing

`standard "src/util/**/*.js" "test/**/*.js"`

How do we get the same functionality by requiring it like other `npm modules`

For ex: `const standard = require("standard");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to install the `standard` module using the following command.

```
npm install standard
```

Then you can use the various functions in the `standard` module's [NodeJS API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/standard#is-there-a-nodejs-api).

Example:

```
const standard = require('standard');
standard.lintFiles('/path/to/files/*.js', function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(res);
  }
});
```